# Beamer - writing a macro to uncover only item i of a enumerate in a frame

Tags: beamer, overlays, programming

I would like to repeat a certain frame at multiple locations in my talk.
However, at each time, I want either all the items to be uncovered
or only item i to be uncovered.
How do I define a macro which is able to generate a frame
with either all the items uncovered
or only item i uncovered?

---

### Example

The following code generates 4 slides.

1. All items uncovered
2. Only item 3 uncovered
3. Only item 1 uncovered
4. Only item 2 uncovered

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Repeating frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 1}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 2}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Repeating frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 1}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 2}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Repeating frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 1}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 2}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Repeating frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 1}
\item \uncover<1>{The is item 2}
\item \uncover<0>{The is item 3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to instead use the following more concise code to generate the same output:

```
\repeatingframe{0}
\repeatingframe{3}
\repeatingframe{1}
\repeatingframe{2}
```

How do I define the macro `\repeatingframe` in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than define a new command, I would use the `\againframe` facility offered by `beamer` itself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<4>[label=repeater]{Repeating frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \uncover<1,4>{The is item 1}
      \item \uncover<2,4>{The is item 2}
      \item \uncover<3-4>{The is item 3}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<1>{repeater}
  \againframe<2>{repeater}
  \againframe<3>{repeater}

\end{document}
```

[image: repeating a repeater frame with variations]

If this is a one-off and you really want to use a specific command to repeat this particular frame, you could try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand<>{\repeatingframe}{%
  \againframe#1{repeater}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<4>[label=repeater]{Repeating frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \uncover<1,4>{The is item 1}
      \item \uncover<2,4>{The is item 2}
      \item \uncover<3-4>{The is item 3}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \repeatingframe<1>
  \repeatingframe<2>
  \repeatingframe<3>

\end{document}
```

This produces the same output but is somewhat less flexible.

```
\newcommand<>{\repeatingframe}[1]{%
  \againframe#2{#1}}
```

would allow you to write

```
\repeatingframe<1>{repeater}
```

so that you could use the same command with different labels for different frames i.e. similar syntax (just one more argument) but much more flexibility. However, you might as well use `\againframe` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution via a simple `\ifnum #1=xx ... \else ... \fi` conditional check.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\repeatingframe}[1]{
\ifnum #1=0   
\def\a{1} \def\b{1} \def\c{1}
\else \ifnum #1=3
\def\a{0} \def\b{0} \def\c{1}
\else \ifnum #1=1
\def\a{1} \def\b{0} \def\c{0}
\else \ifnum #1=2
\def\a{0} \def\b{1} \def\c{0}
\fi
\fi
\fi
\fi
\begin{frame}{Repeating frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \uncover<\a>{The is item 1}
\item \uncover<\b>{The is item 2}
\item \uncover<\c>{The is item 3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\repeatingframe{0}
\repeatingframe{3}
\repeatingframe{1}
\repeatingframe{2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general approach where you can also determine the total ammount of items and give alternate titles to single frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{theitem1}{The is item 1}
\@namedef{theitem2}{The is item 2}
\@namedef{theitem3}{The is item 3}
\@namedef{theitem4}{The is item 4}
\@namedef{theitem5}{The is item 5}
\@namedef{theitem6}{The is item 6}
\@namedef{theitem7}{The is item 7}
\newcount\uncovered
\newcount\uncovermax
\newcommand{\repeatingframe}[3][Repeating frame]{%
  \uncovermax#3
  \begin{frame}{#1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \itemprocess{#2}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}
}
\newcommand{\itemprocess}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \uncovered#1
  \ifnum\uncovered=0
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\the\uncovermax}{%
      \item \uncover<1>{\csname theitem\n\endcsname}}
  \else
    \ifnum\uncovered>1
      {\advance\uncovered by -1
      \foreach \n in {1,...,\the\uncovered}{%
        \item \uncover<0>{\csname theitem\n\endcsname}}}
    \fi
    \item \uncover<1>{\csname theitem\the\uncovered\endcsname}
    \ifnum\uncovered<\uncovermax
      {\advance\uncovered by 1
      \foreach \n in {\the\uncovered,...,\the\uncovermax}{%
        \item \uncover<0>{\csname theitem\n\endcsname}}}
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\repeatingframe{0}{3}
\repeatingframe{3}{3}
\repeatingframe{1}{3}
\repeatingframe{2}{3}

%for testing the generalized version
%\repeatingframe[Repeating frame with different title]{1}{7}
%\repeatingframe{2}{7}
%\repeatingframe{3}{7}
%\repeatingframe{4}{7}
%\repeatingframe{5}{7}
%\repeatingframe{6}{7}
%\repeatingframe{7}{7}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]